# Encrypt a file to be accessed with 2 passwords

Tags: encryption

I would like to encrypt a file, but have it be accessible using one of two passwords.

Here is my use case: I'm writing a program that will allow users to have multiple files, all encrypted and accessible with a single, "private" password. For each file, the user can create a separate, "shared" password (different for each file) that they can then share to give someone else access to that file. Basically, each file can be decrypted using either of the two passwords.

As a security requirement, the software will not store either of the passwords, nor will it store the hashes of those passwords. That means that I cannot combine the passwords or hashes; they have to be usable independently of one another.

Is there an encryption algorithm or method that I can use to implement this behavior? I do not intend on re-implementing cryptography algorithms, so I'll be looking for an open-source implementation if I can determine an appropriate algorithm to look for.

Comment: This probably belongs on [crypto.se]

Comment: Questions about cryptography that do not include an implementation problem are off-topic for Stack Overflow. You may wish to consider posting this at http://crypto.stackexchange.com. You may also wish to consider http://security.stackexchange.com.

Answer (score 4):

Generate a key that you encrypt the file with. Then place two encrypted version of the key in the file, encrypted by use of each of the passwords. This way you can decrypt the file if you know one of the passwords.

Comment: The problem with this is that there is nothing stopping someone from using the shared password to obtain the root key the file is encrypted with. Even if the shared password were "revoked" (by deleting the encrypted shared password key), an attacker could still decrypt the file using the root key they obtained with the shared password. And if this were acceptable to op, it would simply be easier to encrypt the file twice (separately) with two different passwords, rather than create a scheme like this.

Comment: What shared password ? Two different passwords allows decrypt of a key generated for this file. This is a common scheme used by many products - pgp comes to mind.

Comment: Op defines a "private" password and a "shared" password. Shared as in it's shared with someone else. Upon further thought though, I suppose this is a reasonable solution. I would add though that op should take care not to reuse the same root key for a file when modifying and re-encrypting it.